# config/environments/development.rb vs loading in initializer file

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-6

Action mailer does not see the api key when the following is moved into an initializer file instead of my environment/development.rb file.

```
Rails.application.configure do
  config.action_mailer.sendgrid_actionmailer_settings = {
    api_key: 'abc123',
    raise_delivery_errors: true
  }
end
```

Why would moving the following code into an initializer file instead of my development.rb file make the api_key unavailable?

Comment: What is an exact code that you've put in the initializer file?

Comment: The exact above code

Comment: And to be completely sure, did you set `config.action_mailer.delivery_method = :sendgrid_actionmailer` as found for example in [this article](https://hixonrails.com/ruby-on-rails-tutorials/ruby-on-rails-action-mailer-configuration/#sendgrid-rails-config) as well as in [`sendgrid-actionmailer` gem usage docs](https://github.com/eddiezane/sendgrid-actionmailer#usage) too?